# systemctl not found on debian squeeze

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze

I want to execute

```
systemctl enable  perl-fcgi.service
```

But I get

```
bash: systemctl: command not found
```

Why is there no systemctl on debian 6.0 and how can I get it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's in the `systemd` package.  It's not there because you haven't installed it.